# Why exported composite raster of Landsat scenes split into two files? One with a size 1.2 GB and the other with only 60 MB

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, landsat

There is a problem with exporting a Landsat-based composite which I show in below image. Exported image was cut into two mutually exclusive regions which together make the whole area.

[image]

Can I export the composite as one raster file?

```
print (roi) // feature collection with 44 elements

// Creating the composite 
var composite = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_TOA")
             .filterBounds(roi)
             .filterDate('2015-04-01','2015-07-01')
             .select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B6','B7'])
             .reduce(ee.Reducer.mean()); 
             
// Exporting the composite
Export.image.toDrive({
  image: composite.clipToCollection(roi),
  description: 'composite1',
  folder: 'composite1',
  crs: 'EPSG:32638',
  region: roi.geometry().bounds(),
  scale: 30,
  maxPixels: 1e13
});
```

[link to the GEE code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5225bd7e0d6b1b321d0bceb8af03f542)

[link for my roi](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/taghdisian90/Aras_Subwatershed)

Comment: Thank you Daniel. I have just looked at your suggested answer. Could you just tell me what you mean by VRT? and I would appreciate if you have any advice on how to export huge raster file (like composite Landsat data on national level) from GEE.

Comment: VRT: https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html

Comment: You can in principal do what you're doing. If you're having problems with the export, you can tile your region and export the tiles individually.